# read false/true from JSON and validate using == in python

Tags: python, json

I am reading JSON file in Python 3 and trying validate the data.

JSON file:

```json
RESULT": {
        "roo": [
            {
                "success": "true",
                "not ok": "false",
                "
```

Python code:

```
#reading json file
with open('alerts.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

#need to validate
success= "true"
not ok= "false"
#validate
for alert in RESULT['roo']:
    if alert['true'] == success:
        print('true')
```

Using this logic I am able to validate other data successfully, but there are issues in comparing true and false.

I want to validate true with true and false with false.
In python `true == true` is not working. Why?

Comment: What issues are you having? True and False in json are not strings, where is the data coming from?

Comment: Perhaps you would like to post a [mre] and a valid example of the JSON you are parsing.

Comment: You need to change string True to integer True and same goes for false

Comment: Also ```not ok``` is not a valid variable name

Comment: Your example doesn't use the json data at all...

Answer (score 0):

`not ok`is not a valid variable it should be `not_ok` and the code you're looking for is

```
import json
jsonData = {'roo':[{"success": "true","not ok": "false"}]}
json = json.loads(json.dumps(jsonData))

if json['roo'][0]['success'] == 'true':

    print('True')
```